# How to add an extra field in the registration form generated by devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I'm learning Ruby, OOP and Rails.

My app uses the Devise gem for registering users.

It only offers the fields `email`, `password`, and `password confirmation`, but I need an extra field, `phone number`.

What is the correct way to add it? (Not just in the html file)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) You need to add the extra fields to your User Model...

`rails g migration AddPhoneNumberToUser phone_number:string`

2) Configure Strong Parameters in ***ApplicationController***

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:phone_number])
  end
end
```

NOTE: if you already have custom controllers, you just need to uncomment (overhide) `RegistrationsController#sign_up_params` method

3) Generate devise views (if you didn't it yet)

`rails generate devise:views`

4) Add extra fields to form in ***app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb***

Comment: It worked! I was omitting the first step.. Thank you!